# How to resend SMS verification in firebase phone authentication in angular4?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am working on angular 4 and ionic 3 project. In the project, I have implemented firebase phone authentication for login page. I need to implement resend otp functionality when OTP expired/incorrect. How can I implement the resend otp functionality of firebase in angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @srujana please look into [Firebase OTP Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)!.

```
grecaptcha.reset(window.recaptchaWidgetId);
```

Or, if you haven't stored the widget ID:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) { 
   grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
}
```

In case if this doesn't work out please post the part of the code you have used to send OTP for reference.

Comment: hey @naveen,
the example you've provided is about 'reset' recapture and the question is about 'resend' verification code

Comment: @DmytroTolkachov when you reset the recapcha and continue with the same code for sending OTP it would work as expected.